# Class is implemented in both. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I am receiving the following console log when I build and run my iOS app:

> objc[9649]: Class _TtGCs23_ContiguousArrayStorageFT_T__ is implemented in both /Users/dev/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A11B5AFE-ED28-47BF-BFB8-5EDB46004B0B/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/15B4ED39-635D-4E6D-87C4-97E0D2E1F27E/SampleProject.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x1066ef200) and ?? (0x7faca8875de8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Based on the solution in this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46932341/class-is-implemented-in-both-one-of-the-two-will-be-used-which-one-is-undefine), I tried removing the framework entries for Cocoapod libraries that I had recently added (PromiseKit, Fabric, Crashlytics, Instabug) but there was no change in the console logs. Can someone help me understand how to solve this issue?

Here is the podfile:

```
platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'SampleProject' do

use_frameworks!

inhibit_all_warnings!

pod 'Auth0', '~> 1.0'
pod 'SlideMenuControllerSwift', '~> 4.0'
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.7'
pod 'AlamofireImage', '~> 3.3'
pod 'Pulley'
pod 'Floaty', '~> 4.0.0'
pod 'LinearProgressBar'
pod 'Presentr'
pod 'JTAppleCalendar', '~> 7.0'
pod 'GSMessages'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.7.11'
pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.10.7'
pod 'PromiseKit/CorePromise', '~> 6.0'
pod 'PromiseKit/Alamofire', '~> 6.0'
pod 'Instabug'

target 'SampleProjectTests' do
inherit! :search_paths
end

target 'SampleProjectUITests' do
inherit! :search_paths
end

end

post_install do |installer|
installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings.delete('CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED')
    config.build_settings.delete('CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED')
end

installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
if config.name == 'Release'
  config.build_settings['SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL'] = '-Owholemodule'
else
  config.build_settings['SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL'] = '-Onone'
end
end
end
```

Comment: Please share your Podfile

Comment: @PaulBeusterien Sorry, Podfile is now included