# Module not found inside 'Framework' -Swift.h file

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, ios-frameworks, google-ad-manager

I have created this sample Swift framework which has `GoogleMobileAds` in it integrated through Cocoapods. I have a class `NativeAdView` which inherits from `GADNativeAdView`.

```
import GoogleMobileAds

@objc public class NativeAdView: GADNativeAdView {
    
}
```

I also have a sample target which is an Objective-C app. I import the framework header as below in my ***AppDelegate.m***.

```
#import <SampleFramework/SampleFramework-Swift.h>
```

Now when I run the Objective-C target it throws an error inside the file ***SampleFramework-Swift.h***

```
@import GoogleMobileAds; -------- Module 'GoogleMobileAds' not found.
```

However, if I change the parent class of `NativeAdView` to anything other than a Google ad class the error goes away and the build compiles and runs successfully.

Also `@import GoogleMobileAds;` line goes away from ***SampleFramework-Swift.h*** file

I can't figure out what is happening.

Github link - https://github.com/rishabdutta/FrameworkSample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, update bundle identifiers of your targets SampleFramework, SampleSwift, SampleObjc to be different.

Try updating Podfile as follows. Cocoapods works this way that in your setup you have to specify 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK' for every target which uses it, but to avoid copying that line, you can use `abstract_target` so the dependency is automatically added to all targets inside:

```
use_frameworks!

abstract_target 'Common' do
  pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'

  target 'SampleFramework' do
  end

  target 'SampleObjc' do
  end

  target 'SampleSwift' do
  end
end
```

But this way you will face a runtime warning "Class APMAdExposureReporter is implemented in both ...", but the app will work, the warning doesn't cause real problems - [it's discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46932341/class-is-implemented-in-both-one-of-the-two-will-be-used-which-one-is-undefine), but personally I don't know the best practice how to deal with it.

Comment: brother  this not work